# Python cannot validate the == operator even the condition is matched

Tags: python, email, smtp

Im creating a Django web and able to let user select which parameter to parse the email ingestion function. When user click on "OK", the email ingest function will take the input parameter and validate through the if else statement . User can validate through Subject or text of an email and then it can parse with three conditions: equals, contain and does not contain. The subject part is all fine but when come to the text part, the equals is not functioning. It always return me no email even I entered the correct input to match. The main function of this program is able to send an email to a particular user when the condition is triggered. I tried to print the `body.encode` , `valuetomatch` and `GetCondition` all is matched but it still couldn't validate through the equals.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
import email
import imaplib
import mailbox
import smtplib

def index(request):

    return render(request,'DemoApp/hi.html')



def send(request):
    EMAIL_ACCOUNT = "xxx@gmail.com"
    PASSWORD = "xxx"

    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
    mail.list()
    mail.select('inbox')
    result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "UNSEEN")  # (ALL/UNSEEN)
    i = len(data[0].split())

    for x in range(i):
        latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
        result, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
        # result, email_data = conn.store(num,'-FLAGS','\\Seen')
        # this might work to set flag to seen, if it doesn't already
        raw_email = email_data[0][1]
        raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

        # Header Details
        date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(email_message['Date'])
        if date_tuple:
            local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
            local_message_date = "%s" % (str(local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")))
        email_from = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['From'])))
        email_to = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['To'])))
        subject = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['Subject'])))

        # Body details
        for part in email_message.walk():

            if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                print("From:", email_from)

                print("Email To:", email_to)
                print("date:", local_message_date)
                print("Subject:", subject)
                print("body:", body.decode('utf-8'))

                #Get all value from
                ParameterGet = str(request.POST.get('Parameter', None))
                ConditionGet = str(request.POST.get('Condition', None))
                valuetomatch = str(request.POST["valuetomatch"])

                def emailSendDetails():
                    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                    server.starttls()
                    server.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
                    msg = "ALERT NOTICE!"
                    server.sendmail(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, "xxx@gmail.com", msg)
                    server.quit()

                #<----------------Parameter---------------->
                #Subject
                if ParameterGet == "Subject":
                    # <----------------Condition---------------->
                    #Equals
                    if ConditionGet == "Equals":
                        if valuetomatch == subject:
                            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                            server.starttls()
                            server.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
                            msg = "subject equals!"
                            server.sendmail(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, "xxx@gmail.com", msg)
                            server.quit()
                        else:
                            print("no email");

                    # Contain
                    if ConditionGet == "Contain":
                        if valuetomatch in subject:
                            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                            server.starttls()
                            server.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
                            msg = "subject contain!"
                            server.sendmail(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, "xxx@gmail.com", msg)
                            server.quit()
                        else:
                            print("no email");

                    # Does not contain
                    if ConditionGet == "NotContain":
                        if valuetomatch not in subject:
                            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                            server.starttls()
                            server.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
                            msg = "subject not contain!"
                            server.sendmail(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, "xxx@gmail.com", msg)
                            server.quit()
                        else:
                            print("no email");


                # <----------------Parameter---------------->
                #Text
                if ParameterGet == "Text":
                    # <----------------Condition---------------->
                    # Equals
                    if ConditionGet == "Equals":
                        if valuetomatch == body.decode('utf-8'):
                            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                            server.starttls()
                            server.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
                            msg = "text equals!"
                            server.sendmail(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, "xxx@gmail.com", msg)
                            server.quit()
                        else:
                            print("no email");

                    # Contain
                    if ConditionGet == "Contain":
                        if valuetomatch in body.decode('utf-8'):
                            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                            server.starttls()
                            server.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
                            msg = "text contain!"
                            server.sendmail(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, "xxx@gmail.com", msg)
                            server.quit()
                        else:
                            print("no email");

                    # Does not contain
                    if ConditionGet == "NotContain":
                        if valuetomatch not in body.decode('utf-8'):
                            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                            server.starttls()
                            server.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
                            msg = "text notcontain!"
                            server.sendmail(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, "xxx@gmail.com", msg)
                            server.quit()
                        else:
                            print("no email");
                else:
                    continue

    return render(request, 'DemoApp/hi.html', {'key': "Send successfully"})

    '''
    a=str(request.POST["Parameter"])
    b=str(request.POST["Condition"])
    c=str(request.POST["valuetomatch"])
    
    haha = a+b+c
    return render(request,'DemoApp/hi.html',{'key':haha})

    '''


# Create your views here.
```

HTML template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,500" rel="stylesheet">

<style>

body {font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;}
.button {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color:  #ff9633;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left:500px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 45%;

  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #ff9633;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #ff9633;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff9633;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color:
#fa7d34;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<ul>

  <li><div id="myBtn1"><a href="#AddCon">Alert Policies</a></div></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Test3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Test4</a></li>
</ul>



<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Alert Policies</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <p style="font-size:14px">Please select an event parameter as well as the condition type and value that apply.</p>

        <!-- parameter drop down -->
            <form action="{% url 'test' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="Parameter"> <b style="font-size:13px" >  Event parameter to evaluate </b></label>
            <select name="Parameter" id="Parameter" style="width:340px; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;">
                <option disabled selected value>select a parameter</option>
                <option value="Subject">Subject</option>
                <option value="Text">Text</option>

            </select>
            <br><br>

            <label for="Condition">   <b style="font-size:13px" >  Type of condition </b></label>
            <select name="Condition" id="Condition" style="width:340px; margin-left:69px; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;">
                <option disabled selected value>select a condition</option>
                <option value="Equals">Equals</option>
                <option value="Contain">Contain</option>
                <option value="NotContain">Does not contain</option>

            </select>
            <br><br>

            <label for="valuetomatch"> <b style="font-size:13px" > Value to match</b></label>
            <input type="text" id="valuetomatch" name="valuetomatch" style="width:333px; margin-left:80px; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;">
            <br>
            <br>
<button class="button"><span>OK</span></button>
  </form>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>

<h1>    {{key}}   </h1>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Image of my website  :

[image]

As you can see i printed all the three input, even thought it all matched, but it still couldnt work

```
      print(ConditionGet)
      print(valuetomatch)
      print( body.decode('utf-8'))
```

[image]

Comment: Do the length of the `body.decode('utf-8'))` match `valuetomatch` ? It seems that the decoded body includes linebreak at the end. What would be the result if you try to compare `body.decode('utf-8').rstrip()` with `valuetomatch`?

Comment: Hey bro, thanks for the reply. Finally I solved the issue by stripping down the `body.decode`